# How to show all possible route from source to destination in Google map ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-directory-api

I want to implement a similar feature as shown as below Image in my iOS App but I don't find how to get it done. I want a similar to be done.

[image]

but still not able to get it done. By using [this url](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints)  i am able to get direction from source to destination but not multiple path like shown in image

```
NSString *direApi = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=false",
                                               srcLocation.latitude,
                                               srcLocation.longitude,
                                               desLoc.latitude,
                                               desLoc.longitude];
```

thanks for help in advance..

Answer (score 3):

For the Google Maps direction service to provide more than one route alternative, you may add `alternatives` parameter (one of the [optional parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters)) when sending your directions request.

Then, after getting direction from source to destination with the use of [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsRequests), you can use [shapes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes) such as a [polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes#polylines) in plotting paths and routes on your map.

Here are the steps in adding a polyline:

> 1. Create a `GMSMutablePath` object.
> 2. Set the points in the path with the `addCoordinate:` or `addLatitude:longitude:` methods.
> 3. Instantiate a new `GMSPolyline` object using the path as an argument.
> 4. Set other properties, such as `strokeWidth` and `strokeColor`, as desired.
> 5. Set the `map` property of the `GMSPolyline`.
> 6. The polyline appears on the map.

After you have added a polyline, you may also make modifications to it. However, as noted in the documentation, please ensure that you keep hold of the `GMSPolyline` object.

To improve the appearance of the line or change the color, you can also try the following:

- [Customize a polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes#customize_a_polyline)
- [Change the color of a polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes#change_the_color_of_a_polyline)
- [Change the color of individual line segments](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes#change_the_color_of_individual_line_segments)
- [Add a repeating color pattern to a polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes#add_a_repeating_color_pattern_to_a_polyline)

You may also find sample codes in the given links. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
private func drowRoute(){

let path = GMSMutablePath()
    path.addLatitude(self.lat!, longitude: self.long!)
    path.addLatitude(self.destLat!, longitude: self.destLong!)
let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
polyline.strokeWidth = 2.0
polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
polyline.geodesic = true
polyline.map = mappView
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details in your answer. Even if your answer is a complete solution, the asker will learn more if you take the time to explain what your code does, and how you came up with it.

Comment: This is small line of code to draw route path from source location (user location) to destination location. I have follow Google Maps Doc.Please use and perfect working.